# Vuejs: how do you pass class(classes) to template?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What is the right syntax to pass class to `%item.class%` in the following code? Any syntax like `[item.class]` or `{{ item.class }}` passes it as string without render. How to pass it properly?

How to pass several classes and apply to several tags (a, span etc.) nested in one template? Pass an array? How to iterate it?

```
<component v-for="item in List" 
                :item="item"
                :class="item.class"
</component>


let component = Vue.component('component', {
       props: ['item'],
       template: `<li class=" %item.class% ">
                     <a class="fa %item.class% "></a>
                     <span class="fa %item.class%"></span>
                  </li>`
       }),
       data: function (){
        return {
            List: [
                {key:0, class:'someClass'},

            ]
        }
    },
 })
```

Thanks beforehands :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:  You can pass an object to `v-bind:class` `:class` to dynamically toggle classes:

```
<li :class="item.class">
                     <a class="fa" :class="item.class"></a>
                     <span class="fa" :class="item.class"></span>
                  </li>
```

Binding HTML Classes

- Object Syntax :

```
<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>
```

```
data: {
  isActive: true
}
```

- Array Syntax:

```
<div v-bind:class="[activeClass, errorClass]"></div>
```

```
data: {
  activeClass: 'active',
  errorClass: 'text-danger'
}
```

[More Info Official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes)

Answer (score 4):

```
<li :class="item.class">
<a class="fa" :class="item.class">
```

Answer (score 3):

You could separate the bound classes from the no-bound ones :

```
 template: `<li :class="item.class">
                     <a class="fa" :class="item.class"></a>
                     <span class="fa" :class="item.class"></span>
                  </li>`
```